# Highcharts how to create dot hover at end of line chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart

I have a line chart that has no interactivity and needs to have the final data point mimic the hover circle dot of the color of the line.

Image should show what I am trying to get after - how can you do this?

Thanks,
Daniel!

[What I am trying to acomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpYuz.png)

Comment: Increased size of marker should be left after hover or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use marker. it will help you.

```
marker: {
    radius: 10,
    symbol:'url'
  }
```

here is a js fiddle that will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/GJ64x/

hope this will be useful for you.

thanks

Comment: This should accomplish what I need.

Comment: So this fixes part of it - I also need no hover state and no markers on the rest of the chart except this one point.

Comment: use other options of marker in plotOptions , check this http://jsfiddle.net/GJ64x/1/ it will help